# Visibility changed programmatically does not match with weights

Tags: android, scala, layout, resize, visibility

When I change the visibility, layout remains the same and is not resized as expected.
Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<GameView
    android:id="@+id/gameview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/code"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code from my activity:

```
lazy val mCodeView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.code).asInstanceOf[TextView]

def changeState() = {
  mCodeView.setVisibility(if(mCodeView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
}
```

When I call `changeState()`, however, the Codeview disappear, but the GameView is not resized. Why and how to automatically resize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed it to work by adding a LinearLayout enclosing the GameView and another enclosing the TextView, and changing the weights of these LinearLayouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5">
        <GameView
            android:id="@+id/gameview"
            android:id="@+id/gameview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"  />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my code:

```
private lazy val mLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.layout2).asInstanceOf[LinearLayout]

val params = mLayout2.getLayoutParams().asInstanceOf[LinearLayout.LayoutParams]
params.weight = 4f - params.weight
mLayout2.getParent().requestLayout()
```

Hope it will help someone having the same issue one day.

Comment: The getParent().requestLayout portion was what fixed my problem.